# How to change width and box when using aria?

Tags: html, frontend, wai-aria

I using a library for datalist/autocomplate. But I want to change the width and shape of the data container. How do I remove arrow in red box and make the width is dynamic according to content? No css used.
[Link for the library(awesomplete)](https://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/)
[image: current image]

```html
<div class="awesomplete">
  <input id="sellerId" name="sellerId" autocomplete="off" aria-   expanded="false" aria-owns="awesomplete_list_1">
    <ul role="listbox" id="awesomplete_list_1" hidden="">
      <li role="option" aria-selected="false" id="awesomplete_list_1_item_0"><mark>anush</mark>a - harsha</li>
      <li role="option" aria-selected="false" id="awesomplete_list_1_item_1">SRIKAN874 - <mark>anush</mark>
      </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: this arrow will be in `::before` in css, put the link of library and we'll help change it

Comment: @AbdelrahmanGobarah. Please check the link I added in question

Answer (score 0):

to remove the arrow just add this css

```
.awesomplete > ul:before {
    display: none !important;
}
```

---

**Working Sample**

```css
.awesomplete > ul:before {
    display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/awesomplete.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/awesomplete@1.1.5/awesomplete.min.js"></script>

<input class="awesomplete" data-list="#mylist" />
<ul id="mylist" style="display:none;">
  <li>Ada</li>
  <li>Java</li>
  <li>JavaScript</li>
  <li>Brainfuck</li>
  <li>LOLCODE</li>
  <li>Node.js</li>
  <li>Ruby on Rails</li>
</ul>
```

---

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: I tested it with the original file, it works, but with my code is doesn't. Thank you btw. I'll try to figure this out. Btw, I'm using spring boot.